# How to upload images to a new unique folder every session php

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I'm in the process of making a website for my dad that allows people to upload their own personal images because he is a window cleaning tech. He wants to allow people to be able to upload their images so he can give them an estimate on the cost. Below, I have two bits of code. The first bit successfully uploads images. That I won't have to worry about. The second bit, however, does not successfully upload images. What I want to accomplish is that every time a user uploads a set of images (maximum of 5), it will make a new folder in a directory that sets the current time as the name of the folder, that way it will be easier for him to keep track of who sends what. I'm still working out little details on how he can identify a person solely based on images (perhaps a person will call after sending the images in and verify the time of submission?). I am trying to do this with as little use for a database as possible, being I don't know how to use MySQL and tie it to PHP.

This is the code that works and successfully uploads the images to /upload:

```
<?php
    $uploadpath = 'upload/';
    $max_size = 4000;
    $allowtype = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpe', 'png');
    if(isset($_FILES['fileup']) && strlen($_FILES['fileup']['name']) > 1){
        $uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);
        $sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fileup']['name']));
        $type = end($sepext);
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name']);
        $err = '';
        if(!in_array($type, $allowtype)) $err .= 'The file: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['name']. '</b> does not have an allowed extension type.';
        if($_FILES['fileup']['size'] > $max_size*1000) $err .= '<br/>Your file exceeds the '. $max_size. ' KB. size limit.';
        if($err == ''){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)){ 
                echo 'File: <b>'. basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']). '</b> successfully uploaded:';
                echo '<br/>File type: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['type'] .'</b>';
            }
            else echo '<b>Unable to upload the file.</b>';
        }
        else echo $err;
    }
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload File: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
    Upload File: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
    Upload File: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
    Upload File: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
    Upload File: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Upload" /> 
</form>
```

And here's the code I'm trying to change to make a new folder with the timestamp as the name:

```
<?php
    $uploadpath = 'upload/';
    $max_size = 4000;
    $allowtype = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpe', 'png');
    if(isset($_FILES['fileup']) && strlen($_FILES['fileup']['name']) > 1){
        $uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);
        $sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fileup']['name']));
        $type = end($sepext);
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name']);
        $err = '';
        if(!in_array($type, $allowtype)) $err .= 'The file: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['name']. '</b> does not have an allowed extension type.';
        if($_FILES['fileup']['size'] > $max_size*1000) $err .= '<br/>Your file exceeds the '. $max_size. ' KB. size limit.';
        if($err == ''){
            $uploadpath = "upload/" . time();
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($_FILES['fileup']['name'] as $filename){
                $temp = $_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'][$count];
                move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploadpath . '/' . $filename);
                $count++;
            }
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)){ 
                echo 'File: <b>'. basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']). '</b> successfully uploaded:';
                echo '<br/>File type: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['type'] .'</b>';
            }
            else echo '<b>Unable to upload the file.</b>';
        }
        else echo $err;
    }
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload File: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
    Upload File: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
    Upload File: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
    Upload File: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
    Upload File: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Upload" /> 
</form>
```

the main difference between the two is after the `if($err == '')`, the second bit of code has one more block here to replace the original "move file" command

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar for my uncle's company. To solve your issue of not knowing a good way to have the person submit there info you can create a form that takes info and then sends an email to your dad's work email. Here's an example of the php mail function.

```
$to = 'service@anywhere.com';
$subject = 'New Service Request:';
$time = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$body = "New Service Request Submited - $time (time is coming from webserver)\nFirst   Name: ".$_POST['fname']."
Last Name:\n ".$_POST['lname']."
Title:\n ".$_POST['title']."
Business:\n ".$_POST['business']."
Phone:\n ".$_POST['phone']."
Email:\n ".$_POST['email']."
Address:\n ".$_POST['address']."
Preferred Method of Contact:\n ".$method."
Equipment Type:\n ".$_POST['type']."
Equipment Issue:\n ".$_POST['issue']."
Additional Comments:\n ".$_POST['comments'];
$headers = 'From: Request Generator <noreply@anything.com>';
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Email address can be anything you want. Only requirement is that you have a mail server running where your website is (pretty much all hosting companies provide an email server in addition to the webserver). in the header section, you will notice the text in front of . That text shows up as the name of the 'person' who sent the email and the text between the <> is the 'address' it comes from which again doesn't have to be real.

In my body I left the text that generates tickets for my uncle to provide an example of what you may or may not want your tickets to look like.

For your upload error at first glance it looked like you never created the dynamic folder the content is being uploaded into. Try:

```
mkdir($uploadpath);
```

before you create or move any files in the directory.

Comment: I do have an email by my hosting, but I'm on the most basic plan at the moment being I'll never reach 6GB of traffic a month because my website is so small, but due to this, my hosting blocks the SMTP outbound, and support won't teach me how to set this up myself inline with my personal-made code. But anyway, would I add the `mkdir($uploadpath);` right after the `if($err == ''){` line? I will consider the email portion as well, but I make all my websites from my domain before transferring them, so it is quite difficult to test email scripts. None of them work, actually...

Comment: also, how do I use the mkdir function to make a folder in a directory I'm not currently in

Comment: you would use mkdir($uploadpath); immediately after $uploadpath = "upload/" . time();

Comment: the mkdir function creates the directory at the entered path, so you don't have to be in the directory you want to make a new one in. For example, if you used mkdir('/var/www/uploads/time/'); it would create a directory in the uploads directory called time. If you used mkdir('time'); it would create a directory called time in your current directory

Comment: also, the script I posted works (just swap out the $to variable and use actual variables for your body obviously) and that's all you have to do provided the server php is running on is properly configured. I know you that is works by default on ipower.com